Error when converting python script to executable
I encountered this error when converting my "app.py" file into executable file by using pyinstaller app.py --onefile.

14907 WARNING: Execution of 'copyfile' failed on attempt #1 / 20: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied').
RuntimeError: Execution of 'copyfile' failed - no more attempts left!

I'm only trying to run a simple mouse and keyboard controls with this code:
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.hotkey("win", "r")
pyautogui.write("notepad")
pyautogui.hotkey("enter")
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.moveTo(500, 300, 1)
pyautogui.write("Hello World!", .500)
pyautogui.press("t", 2, 1)
pyautogui.press("e", 2, 1)
pyautogui.press("s", 2, 1)
pyautogui.press("t", 2, 1)


are you running this on Windows machine ? Looks like your user lacks the necessary permissions

Looks like you don't have the permissions; if you're on Windows, launch your terminal as Administrator then run the command

is this full error message? If not then show FULL error message.
